# How to do a stop moviment condition

Tags: actionscript-3

I move a character using sine and cos.

```
player.x += Math.cos(angle) * speed;
player.y += Math.sin(angle) * speed;
```

The current stop condition is `distance < n`. But if speed is too high sometimes the character do not stop and keep going forever. Whats the best way to make it stop the right place?

PS: it moves with mouse click. I click and the player move straight to the clicked point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick workaround would be to check if the current `distance` is shorter than the previous one (the one in the previous animation frame). That would mean that the character is approaching the objective. If it is not approaching it (the current distance is actually higher than the previous one), it means that it has already passed it, so it must stop.

In pseudocode:

```
if distance < n or lastDistance<distance then
    stop;
lastDistance = distance;
```

After stopping, you should locate the character in the target position (otherwise, it will remain static in the overshooted position).

EDIT: If you don't mind the character stopping a bit before it reaches its objective, you may try to use a value of `n` that depends on the current `speed`. That way, if the character is going fast, it will stop when it's inside a bigger area.